# "Not a directory" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have created a directory using mkdir (logged in as root), and cd usually works flawlessly. But for this new directory, I get:

cd: can't cd to /home/bots/irofferMOVIES/files

So I created a different folder called "file", to verify I didn't put an extra space in or something, but I get the same error for this folder too.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you cd'ing as root still? or regular user? What are the file permissions on those folders if you issue an "ls -l"

Comment: Trying as root. ls -l shows:

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       4096 Jul 29 16:44 file

-rw-rw-r-x 1 bots bots   13017088 Jul 29 16:45 files

-rw-r--r-- 1 bots root         26 Jul 29 08:00 footer.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 bots root       1723 Jul 29 08:00 header.html

Comment: well, from that it looks like file should definitely be a directory, files on the other hand is not. I don't know what would have caused it if you used mkdir, or why the "file" directory isn't working for you either.

Check the parent directories permissions, "ls -ld /home/bots/irofferMOVIES" Make sure that it has "x" permissions. Execute permissions on directories are required to traverse them. But at the same time... You shouldn't be having this problem as root...